# Change HTML form action based on option

Tags: jquery, html

### HTML

```
  <select class="form-control input-lg" id="r" name="r">
    <option data-action="/test1">Test1</option>
    <option data-action="/test2">Test2</option>
    <option data-action="/test3">Test3</option>
    <option data-action="/test4">Test4</option>
  </select>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#r').change(function() {
    $("form").attr("action", +$(this).attr("data-action"));
});
```

### Problem

Regardless of selected option the form is submitted to `/NaN.php`. I am not sure what this page is but no such page exists on the site.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do but having one "action handler" per request type seems to be the wrong path. Are you sure you cannot send the `POST` to a single handler with a `requestType` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to get `data-action` of the `select`, not the selected `option`.

```
var form = $("form");
form.attr("action", form.attr('action')+$(this).children(':selected').attr("data-action"));
```

Note also you were assuming that `+` would append the value to the base action; that works only when setting numerical values e.g. CSS properties, and even then is part of the new attribute value (it's jQuery-specific syntax):

```
$('#foo').css('padding-top', '+=15px');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26yd069f/).